# if conditions within htaccess file to execute custom directive

Tags: .htaccess, conditional-statements

I have three sites, 1 site is production, 1 is staging and the other is dev.

For Example....

```
mydomain.com <--live
staging.mydomain.com <---staging
mydevdomain.com <--- dev
```

Each site has exactly the same files and I want to make sure that each site has the same htaccess file (to avoid having to maintain separate htaccess files) but I would like to force www on the live site --> mydomain.com.

Is there some htaccess conditions I can use which does something like this:

```
if({HTTP_HOST} ==  "mydomain.com" { 

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
   RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

}
```

This way when someone goes to mydomain.com they are sent to the www version and on the other sites they stay in non www version.

Answer (score 1):

This is where `RewriteCond` comes in. It is used for conditions.

Try this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```